# How to get count of this query - Select Count (*) from (select AccountId, * from Account) as CountRecord

Tags: sql

How to get Count of this query ?

```
select AccountId, * from Account
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to get as a result? The number of accounts in your Accounttable? If so you do not need a subselect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select Count(*) as CountRecord from Account
```

Answer (score 1):

You have placed alias on wrong place

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountRecord FROM (SELECT AccountId, * FROM Account) a
-----------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But you should directly count the records like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountRecord FROM Account
```

Comment: This query doesn't give any output.. Error is slightly changed as "The column 'AccountId' was specified multiple times for 'a'."

Comment: That is because `select AccountId, * from Account` is meaningless. It means same as `select * from Account` but when you specify accountid separately then you are telling rdbms to bring back accountid two times which generates that error

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, thing is that I have one screen on which user gets output with the query, and I don't want to restrict any user on this condition to don't put any column for twice (as SQl also doesn't do it). And then I need to get count of the query result.

Comment: If sql didn't restrict it, it would not return the error it did

Comment: @himanshupareek66 - You need to give alias to `AccountId` if you want to select it multiple times.

Comment: OK. I got the scenario. And Thanks for the answer.